# How can I put images on top of each other with display:flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a site where I have images centered both vertically and horizontally, and to achieve that I've set their display: flex. I want them to stack and center on top of each other, however.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="space">
    <div>
        <img id="outerrim" class="layer" src="./assets/css/images/outerrim.png">
        <div>
            <img id="innerrim" class="layer" src="./assets/css/images/innerrim.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#space {
    background-image: url("./images/sky.png");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.layer {
    object-fit: contain;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This is what that makes it look like:
[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egxh7.jpg)

I want those two faded images to overlap, but I need the flex CSS to make the images align both vertically and horizontally center.

Any advice?

Comment: If your question is how to center one image in the middle of another, I don't see where the flex comes in. Just set `position:relative` on the parent of the first image and `absolute` on the second image.

Comment: thank you! that's what I get for coding instead of sleeping. I just changed the flex styling to just #outerrim and applied the positioning like you said.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for put them on top of each other flex-box is not the right way. make a `position:relative` container in inside put the images and set to them `position:absolute`. give to them `z-index:[1-100]` with highest value to a top image.